# WooCommerce update cart button has been disabled

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason disabled has been added to the update cart button on the basket page. I able able to get the button using jQuery but I cannot remove disabled even though I am able to apply css to it if I please.

Why is disabled being added to the button?
How do I remove it?

my js inside the footer;

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#basket_page').find('button[name="update_cart"]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
</script>
```

the button html inside the inspector;

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update basket" disabled="">Update basket</button>
```

Comment: You have simply something like a customization that is making that… We can't guess that for you. It could be also some plugin… So as mostly everything is managed by jQuery delegated events and Ajax on cart page, even using jQuery will not allow you to re-enable it. You should better find the guilty instead.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have make changes to the quantity input maybe thats the cause. I'll just keep removing things until I find a solution

Comment: I just deleted my WooCommerce file and the problem was still there.

Comment: I don't understand you. I deleted my WooCommerce template overrides and the button still has disabled on it

Comment: I don't know which customization is the guilty as I can't guess that… You need to disable one by one the last customizations you have done before this behavior has appeared, to find the guilty.

Comment: I removed them all and it was still there. I'll keep looking. Thanks

Comment: Issues are mostly always linked to something we have done…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was going wrong. Inside the WooCommerce js files there is a file called cart.js. Within this file there is some code which checks if the input has been changed, if it has it removes disabled on the update cart button so that you can update the cart. So there a few things that one could do which would conflict with this code. Possible reasons could be;

1. You have edited the template file for the product quantity inputs and now the js can not longer detect if there is a change as you have changed the structure / classes ect.
2. You have created your own js functions that deal with the quantity input and now they are conflicting with the cart.js.

In my case it was reason 2. I figured out that if I grabbed the input inside my js and applied .change() to it whenever I had changed the quantity it fixed this problem. But I preferred to not conflict with the cart.js incase it caused problems later so I simply used other methods to catch when the input had changed.

instead of using .change on the input to catch when the input had been changed I used .on('keydown keyup')

Comment: Any idea how to fix reason 1 please ?

Comment: I'd need more info to help you. What did you change in the template file? Did you remove the WooCommerce Classes? some of those classes are used by the WooCommerce jQuery which detects if the input has changed

Comment: The update basket button is automatically disabled until one of the quantity inputs on the products changes. If the WooCommerce jQuery cannot detect if the input has changed it will remain disabled

Answer (score 2):

I run thru the same issue, and it my case the problem was a modification in the `cart.php` template file on which I had removed the hook responsible of adding classes to the `cart-item`s.

So, if this is your case, fin in your theme the cart template (`yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php`) and inside the *foreach* loop of the products you should include the filter that includes the cart item classes.

```php
<tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
```

You can find [this line originally in the template on Github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.2/templates/cart/cart.php#L47) (As per v3.6.2 of WooCommerce)

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into issues as well. As I looked into the cart.js, and I found this :

```
$( document ).on(
                'change input',
                '.woocommerce-cart-form .cart_item :input',
                this.input_changed );

            $( '.woocommerce-cart-form :input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', true );
        },

        /**
         * After an input is changed, enable the update cart button.
         */
        input_changed: function() {
            $( '.woocommerce-cart-form :input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
        },
```

Clearly to enabled the Update button, you need to have the quantity input value changed. And you look into the event trigger, it is tied to `.woocommerce-cart-form .cart_item :input` which mean it must have this two element in each or the row.

In my case, the `.cart_item` was missing in the DOM, I think this is the woocommerce bug that didn't adding the `cart_item` class into the table tr field.

So the solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class' , 'fixbug_cart_item_class' ,10 , 3 );
function fixbug_cart_item_class( $order_item, $item, $order) {
            $class = ' cart_item';


             return $class;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your footer.php file. It will be kept to enable the button even if you have updated the cart by click on it.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.woocommerce-cart').find('button[name="update_cart"]').prop('disabled', false);

        jQuery('body').on('updated_cart_totals', function() {
            jQuery('.woocommerce-cart').find('button[name="update_cart"]').prop('disabled', false);

        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the attribute with jQuery:

```
jQuery('#basket_page').find('button[name="update_cart"]').removeAttr( 'disabled' )
```